# Loop through columns and delete those that only have zeros

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Posting this from the Stack Exchange app so forgive me if the formatting is a bit off.

Basically, I want to do something really simple. I have a spreadsheet with some data. Headers are on the first row. I want to loop through the columns and delete those where all the rows in that column have a value of zero. If any of the values are nonzero, the column must stay.

Can anyone suggest a succinct, easy to read way of doing this. I want to try to avoid looping, looking for something compact and elegant.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is not too "un-elegant"

```
Sub ColumnKiller()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = N To 1 Step -1
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(Rows.Count, i))) = 0 Then
            Cells(2, i).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1**

The code above will work if there are not *negative* values below the first row.  If the lower rows can contain negative values, then the following code should be used:

```
Sub ColumnKiller2()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction, Kount As Long
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String
    s1 = "=0"
    s2 = "="
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    N = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = N To 1 Step -1
        Set r = Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(Rows.Count, i))
        Kount = wf.CountIf(r, s1) + wf.CountIf(r, s2)
        If Kount = Rows.Count - 1 Then
            Cells(2, i).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Each column is examined and if all the cells below the first row contain either zeros or blanks, that column is deleted.

Comment: @pnuts My **EDIT** should cover the case of a positive value offsetting a negative value.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this today and provide feedback.